# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA when using torrents

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have Lenovo Y5070 (Windows 10).

When I'm using any of torrent programs (Deluge, uTorrent) - I have BSOD Error - PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA.
How can I fix it?

Dump - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwqgt-32OJzcdzlNUDRYTFIxdUU/view
Thank you!

Comment: This bugcheck code is almost always due to a bug in a kernel mode driver or in OS kernel mode code.

Comment: have you tried the newer driver? Does the driver fix the issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

[Analyzing the dmp with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows, that the Broadcom driver `bcmwl63a.sys` is the cause

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except.
Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffa780006f56d8, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff801c2829832, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000002, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for bcmwl63a.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for bcmwl63a.sys


 # Call Site
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MmAccessFault
03 nt!KiPageFault
04 nt!MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool
05 ndis!NdisAllocateMdl
06 bcmwl63a
07 0x0
08 nt!SwapContext
09 0x0
0a 0x0
0b nt!KiDeferredReadyThread

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bcmwl63a.sys
Image name: bcmwl63a.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Mon Jul 20 11:54:40 2015
```

This is the older version 7.35.267.0, try the latest [7.35.344.0](http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=startdown&id=2147&lang=en).